# Receiving "Invalid Date" when attempting to get user input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am trying to calculate the difference between two dates entered by the user with JavaScript; however, I keep receiving InvalidDate. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Assignment Calculator</h1>
    
<form>
    <label for="StartDate">Date to Start:</label>
    <input id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="date"/>

    <label for="DueDate">Due Date:</label> 
    <input id="DueDate" name="DueDate" type="date"/>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="displayDates()">
</form>
    
<script type = "text/javascript" >

// Get start date and due date 

var startInput = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
var dueInput = document.getElementById("DueDate").value;
    
var startDate = new Date(startInput);
var dueDate = new Date(dueInput);

// To calculate the time difference of two dates
var DifferenceInTime = dueDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

// To calculate the no. of days between two dates
var DifferenceInDays = DifferenceInTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

function displayDates() {
//To display the of days a student has to work on the assignment (result)
document.write("Start your assignment by " + startDate + ".<br>"
            + "Finish your assignment by " + dueDate + ".<br> "
            + "You must complete your assignment in this many days: " + DifferenceInDays + ".");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to read the field values to early - the user did not even have a chance to _make_ any input at this point. You need to read them _inside_ your function. And all the rest basically belongs into it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of your javsascript code needs to move *inside* the `displayDates()` function.

When it's outside the code, it immediately runs, so variables like `startInput` and `dueInput` will be set once and never again.

Your goal is to figure out `startInput` and `dueInput` *after* the user clicks the button.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You calling the function on button click but getting the value from on input field at pageload even when the data values are not selected.
you should put that part too inside the function that you are calling on button click.

```
function displayDates() {
    var startInput = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
var dueInput = document.getElementById("DueDate").value;
    
var startDate = new Date(startInput);
var dueDate = new Date(dueInput);

// To calculate the time difference of two dates
var DifferenceInTime = dueDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

// To calculate the no. of days between two dates
var DifferenceInDays = DifferenceInTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
//To display the of days a student has to work on the assignment (result)
document.write("Start your assignment by " + startDate + ".<br>"
            + "Finish your assignment by " + dueDate + ".<br> "
            + "You must complete your assignment in this many days: " + DifferenceInDays + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only needs to move code, which is calculating difference between dates into `displayDates` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Assignment Calculator</h1>
    
<form>
    <label for="StartDate">Date to Start:</label>
    <input id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="date"/>

    <label for="DueDate">Due Date:</label> 
    <input id="DueDate" name="DueDate" type="date"/>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="displayDates()">
</form>
    
<script type = "text/javascript" >


function displayDates() {
    // Get start date and due date 
    var startInput = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
    var dueInput = document.getElementById("DueDate").value;
    
    var startDate = new Date(startInput);
    var dueDate = new Date(dueInput);

    // To calculate the time difference of two dates
    var DifferenceInTime = dueDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    // To calculate the no. of days between two dates
    var DifferenceInDays = DifferenceInTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

    //To display the of days a student has to work on the assignment (result)
    document.write("Start your assignment by " + startDate + ".<br>" 
        + "Finish your assignment by " + dueDate + ".<br> "
        + "You must complete your assignment in this many days: " 
        + DifferenceInDays + ".");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the JavaScript code outside the function into the `displayDates` function.

```
<script>
function displayDates() {
// Get start date and due date 

var startInput = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
var dueInput = document.getElementById("DueDate").value;
    
var startDate = new Date(startInput);
var dueDate = new Date(dueInput);


// To calculate the time difference of two dates
var DifferenceInTime = dueDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

// To calculate the no. of days between two dates
var DifferenceInDays = DifferenceInTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

//To display the of days a student has to work on the assignment (result)
document.write("Start your assignment by " + startDate + ".<br>"
            + "Finish your assignment by " + dueDate + ".<br> "
            + "You must complete your assignment in this many days: " + DifferenceInDays + ".");
}
</script>
```